# Deploy Angular v17 on IIS Server

Tags: angular, iis, deployment, angular17

I'm trying to deploy a simple Angular v17 project without SSR to my companies IIS server with no success.

When I build the application I got 1 folder (browser) inside the dist\AppName folder

I need help to know the steps to deploy the application on IIS

I created a folder on the machine, added the content of the "Browser" folder to it and added the following web config file and added to the assets in angular.json and created a site on IIS, but the application site didn't work

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
      <clear />
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I run this command for the build because my project folder is on a subfolder like this: wwwroot/angular-project

`ng build --base-href "/angular-project/"`

I got this on the console
[image: Console]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to a server misconfiguration where JavaScript bundles don't have the correct Content-Type header set.

> All of your application JavaScript files must be served by the server
> with the  Content-Type header set to text/javascript or another
> JavaScript-compatible MIME-type.
>
> Most servers and hosting services already do this by default.
>
> Server with misconfigured mime-type for JavaScript files will cause an
> application to fail to start with the following error:
>
> ```
> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is
> ```
>
> enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
>
> If this is the case, you will need to check your server configuration
> and reconfigure it to serve .js files with Content-Type:
> text/javascript. See your server's manual for instructions on how to
> do this.

Please refer to this link: [Configuring correct MIME-type for JavaScript assets](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#configuring-correct-mime-type-for-javascript-assets).